# Projection of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading some material on the Householder reflection and it describes the projection of a vector $\vec{x}$, onto $\vec{v}$ in vector notation to be:

$\frac{\vec{x}\cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||^2}\vec{v}$

Where $a\cdot b$ is the dot product of vectors a and b.

So how is that?

I know if θ is the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{v}$, then in trigonometric terms, the projection of $\vec{x}$ on $\vec{v}$ would be $x\cos(θ)$. How are these two equivalent? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Sujaan Kunalan. My post looks much more professional now :-)

Comment: Your welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x.v/v.v)v$ is the projection vector of $x$ onto $v$, while, $|x|\cos\theta=|x|(x.v/|v||x|)=(x.v/|v|)$ is just the length(magnitude) of the projection vector.

projection vector($x$ on $v$) $=(x.v/v)*$ unitvector in direction of $v$ = $(x.v/|v|)(v/|v|)=(x.v/|v|^2)v=(x.v/v.v)v$

Comment: Don't have 15 points to thumb you up, but at least can accept your answer! The second part of your answer alone was sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: Should read: "projection vector(x on v) =(x.v/|v|)... "

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your equation is slightly off. I'll derive the correct equation directly to show you why.

Recall that $x\cdot v = |x||v|\cos(\theta)$

$$\frac{x\cdot v}{v\cdot v}v=\frac{|x||v|\cos(\theta)}{|v|^2}v=|x|\cos(\theta)\frac{v}{|v|}$$

So this vector has length $|x|\cos(\theta)$ and it points in the direction of $v$, which is precisely what the trig should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

First we should understand where the following projection formula comes from:

$$proj_{\vec v}(\vec x)=\left( \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||^2} \right) \vec{v}=\left( \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec v \cdot \vec v} \right)\vec{v}$$

$proj_{\vec v}(\vec x)$ will be in the same direction with $\vec v$. Therefore, we can write $proj_{\vec v}(\vec x)=k \vec v$, for some scalar $k$. Additionally, if you draw these vectors, you see that the vector $(\vec x - proj_{\vec v}(\vec x))$ is orthogonal to $\vec v$. Combining these results, we find that

$$(\vec x-k\vec v) \cdot \vec v=\vec x \cdot \vec v-k(\vec v \cdot \vec v)=0$$

If we take $k$ out of this equation, we get

$$k=\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{v}}{\vec v \cdot \vec v}$$

Replacing $k$ in the $proj_{\vec v}(\vec x)=k \vec v$ gives us the above formula.

The relationship between $\cos(\theta)$ and the projection is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1378160/137035).