# Projection of Vectors v on w

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Given $v = [3, -6, 2]$ and  $w = [-1, 6, 5]$, find;

1. $v \downarrow w$
2. $w \downarrow v$
3. What does the magnitude of $w \downarrow v$ depend on?
4. What does the direction of $w \downarrow v$ depend on?

I have:

1. $[\frac{29}{62},-\frac{87}{31},-\frac{145}{62}]$
2. $[-\frac{87}{49},\frac{174}{49},-\frac{58}{49}]$

For 3 and 4, I don't know what the magnitude of those depend on. I guess they depend on the magnitude of both $w$ and $v$. The direction of that depends also on the previous direction of $w$ and $v$... help?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone looking up vector projection via this question, the basic formula is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/429153/139123

Comment: Nice, it helped.