# How can the area of a paralellogram formed by two 3D vectors be computed without using the cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can the area of the parallelogram formed by two 3D vectors
$$\mathbf{u} = [a, b, c], \space \mathbf{v} = [e, f, g]$$
be computed without using the cross product?

Comment: You may perhaps calculate the angle $\alpha$ between $u$ and $v$ via dot product and then use $A=|u||v|\sin\alpha$, but it is basically the ugly way to calculate the cross product.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $\mathbf v$ as the sum of two components, one parallel to $\mathbf u$ and one orthogonal to $\mathbf u.$
Let $\mathbf v_\perp$ be the orthogonal component.
Then the area of the parallelogram is
$$ \lVert u \rVert\, \lVert \mathbf v_\perp \rVert. $$

---

[Projection of a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429153/projection-of-a-vector) and its answers explain how to get  $\mathbf v_\parallel,$ the parallel component of $\mathbf v.$
And then $\mathbf v_\perp = \mathbf v - \mathbf v_\parallel.$
The effect is the same as the formula in the helpful comment under this answer.

Comment: How can I find the orthogonal component $\mathbf{v}_\perp$ or the length of the component directly?

Comment: @K.Claesson Subtract from $\bf v$ the component of $\bf v$ along $\bf u$. $$\mathbf{v_\perp}=\mathbf v-\frac{\mathbf{v\cdot u}}{\|\mathbf u\|^2}\mathbf u$$

Answer (score 2):

The square of the area is the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\bf{u}\cdot\bf u&\bf{u}\cdot\bf v\\
\bf{v}\cdot\bf u&
\bf{v}\cdot\bf v
\end{vmatrix}.$$

Comment: Could you explain why this is the square of the area?

Comment: @K.Claesson Recall that $A^2=\|\mathbf u\|^2\|\mathbf v\|^2\sin^2\alpha=\|\mathbf u\|^2\|\mathbf v\|^2(1-\cos^2\alpha)=\|\mathbf u\|^2\|\mathbf v\|^2-(\mathbf{u\cdot v})^2$